# Why can my program open COM1 but not COM11?

Tags: c, serial-port

I have tried to read data from sensors. The sensors controller is using db9 header (com1), because I will use com1, I use db9 to usb converter and get com 11.

I have program to read and write to the serial port, it work when I use com1, but when I change to com 11, the program fail to open the com because it reach `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

here is my program for the serial port programming:

```
Serial::Serial(char *portName)

{

this->connected = false;

wchar_t wcPort[64];
 size_t convertedChars = 0;
 mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcPort, strlen(portName), portName, _TRUNCATE);

 this->hSerial = CreateFile(wcPort,
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
0,
NULL,
OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
0);

//Check if the connection was successfull
if(this->hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //If not success full display an Error
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){

        //Print Error if neccessary
        printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available.\n", portName);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR!!!");
    }
}
else
{

    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};


    if (!GetCommState(this->hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {

        printf("failed to get current serial parameters!");
    }
    else
    {


    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_38400;
        dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
        dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
        dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
        dcbSerialParams.fOutX=TRUE;
        dcbSerialParams.fInX=TRUE;



         if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
         {
            printf("ALERT: Could not set Serial Port parameters");
         }
         else
         {

             this->connected = true;


         }
    }
}
```

}

Is it because the software/program or the hardware problem?

when I try with hyperterminal, it can read and write the com 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open COM ports numbered 10 and higher, you need to prefix the name with `\\.\`.

Now, in C, you must escape all those backslashes.  So the port you need to open is `"\\\\.\\COM11"`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that C cannot accept Com more than 9

Comment: @Limavolt It's nothing to do with C.  It's just the way the Win32 API works.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831

Comment: Thank you, my program can recognize the com 11, but It cannot read and write to com port. and If I change the connection to com 1, and I still use  "\\\\.\\COM11" and working (but the connection still in com1)

Comment: @Limavolt Do not use `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` in the call to `CreateFile`.  Use the value `0`.  Please try to be clear about your issue.  You say "recognize", but what do you mean?  Is the call to `CreateFile` successful?  If you're still having problems opening the port, try using `CreateFileA` to avoid the string conversion that you're doing in case something is wrong with that.

Comment: @Limavolt Actually, your `mbstowcs_s` call **is wrong**.  You are supposed to pass the size (in words) of `wcPort` as the third parameter.  That is, `64`, *not* `strlen(portName)`.  Because strings must be NULL-terminated and you have specified `_TRUNCATE`, you'll lose the last character in the string after conversion (instead of the conversion failing).

Comment: thank you @paddy, you saved my days, the problem is appear because the size of wcPort.